How does the Detox automation interact with elements?
it('should navigate user to a location screen when user clicks the Location button on navigation bar (C23938)', async () => {
        await waitFor(LoginScreen.logInButton).toBeVisible().withTimeout(5000);
        await LoginScreen.clickOnLogInButton();
        await ProfileSelectionScreen.selectProfileById(TestData.profileId);
        await NavBar.clickOnLocationNavigationButton();
        await expect(LocationScreen.pageView).toBeVisible(); 
    });

My test looks like this. Basically, pageView is an element that is defined by the testID that is assigned to the scroll view of the page. After some development, we added an actual map on the screen, that has most part of the screen, but yet there are some other elements. Now that we have added a map, the expectation does not work, as it covers a big part of the page itself. In case I write expectations for the map itself the tests passes without any issue. As I understand Detox interacts with the elements in layers. Can I somehow keep the expectation on pageView itself? In case the Map disappears from the page, my test will fail, but theoretically, it should not fail as the page exists and the Location button located on the navbar redirects me there
